# Traefik can't access containers

Tags: reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to solve this problem since days, but I don't get it and I didn't find anything helpful in the internet, so I'd be very grateful for every hint.

A few weeks ago, I set up a new Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS Server. I installed docker and ran an internal web page on it. Now we've got an additional webpage and I'd like to make them accessible with two different subdomains.

- appone.qwert.de
- apptwo.qwert.de

For this reason I bought the domain qwert.de and asked my provider for a fixed ip address. My server is now reachable over the domain qwert.de.

Then I found traefik which does pretty much cover all my needs. So I installed it with the following configuration:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "qwert.de"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "admin@qwert.ch"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

And then I started the container with the following docker-compose command:

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /srv/docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /srv/docker/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Everything works fine and I got the typical "404 page not found" message of traefik. Afterwards, I start a basic nginx container with the following code:

```
sudo docker run -d --label "traefik.frontend.rule=HOST:appone.qwert.ch" --network web nginx:latest
```

But when I now try to call the website appone.qwert.ch I also get the typical "404 page not found" message. The traefik container throws the following error message:

```
level:error msg="Error creating route for frontend frontend-HOST-qwert-de-0: error parsing rule: error parsing rule: 'HOST:qwert.de'. Unknown function: 'HOST'"
```

I don't know if I have to somehow configure the server with the new domain or what I did wrong.

My /etc/hosts/ file looks as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       qwert.de  Linux-Server
127.0.1.1       Linux-Server
212.153.72.45   qwert.de Linux-Server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I'd really appreciate every reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i'm using *Host* instead of *HOST*

> -l "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:appone.qwert.ch"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.